# get previous hour/previous day timestamp from a unix value

Tags: java, timestamp, momentjs, unix-timestamp, days

i have an epoch timestamp of 1567318967 (September 1, 2019 6:22:47 AM). From the given epoch timestamp, How do I get the previous hour and previous day and output the result in epoch using Java?

I.e.

previous hour: output result: 1567315367 (September 1, 2019 5:22:47 AM)

previous day: output result: 1567232567 (August 31, 2019 6:22:47 AM)

Given timestamp of 1567318967 , i have attempt the following

```
       previousDayInEpoch = moment(timestamp).substract(1, days)
       previosHourInEpoch = moment(timestamp).substract(1, hour)
```

Would like to use Java to output the previous Day and previous Hour result.

Comment: It’s almost a duplicate. Search for how to convert your Unix timestamp to a `ZonedDateTime`. Tehn subtracting an hour or a day is trivial, and if it isn’t search for that too. All you’re missing is converting back to a Unix timestamp. You guessed it! Your search engine.

Comment: Does "previous day" mean 24 hours, or does it mean a calendar day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### java.time

This is one of the cases where java.time, the modern Java date and time API, excels:

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Pacific/Kwajalein");
    long originalTimestamp = 1_567_318_967L;
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = Instant.ofEpochSecond(originalTimestamp).atZone(zone);

    long anHourLess = dateTime.minusHours(1).toInstant().getEpochSecond();
    System.out.println("previous hour: " + anHourLess);

    long aDayLess = dateTime.minusDays(1).toInstant().getEpochSecond();
    System.out.println("previous day: " + aDayLess);
```

Output is what you expected:

> ```
> previous hour: 1567315367
> previous day: 1567232567
> ```

### Time zone is crucial

The important thing to notice when subtracting a day is that a day is not always 24 hours. It may sometimes be for example 23 hours, 23.5 hours or 25 hours, for example when going into summer time (DST) and back. `ZonedDateTime` knows the length of this particular day in the time zone specified, so is the class that we need to use. It is therefore also important that you fill in your desired time zone where I put Pacific/Kwajalein.

Edit: To use the system time zone:

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.systemDefault();
```

This uses the default time zone setting of the JVM, which usually is picked up from the OS when the JVM is launched. The setting may however be changed at any time by any program running in the same JVM, so is generally fragile. Use at your own risk (or your user’s own risk).

### If you just wanted 24 hours

> Also curious about using the Instant, would you please update the
>   answer for the other option which is considering 24 hours ago.

In this case we don’t need any time zone nor any `ZonedDateTime`. To subtract an hour or a day (always 24 hours) from an `Instant`, you need to know how. It goes like this:

```
    Instant originalInstant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(originalTimestamp);

    long anHourLess = originalInstant.minus(1, ChronoUnit.HOURS).getEpochSecond();
    System.out.println("previous hour: " + anHourLess);

    long aDayLess = originalInstant.minus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS).getEpochSecond();
    System.out.println("previous day: " + aDayLess);
```

In this case the output is identical to the one above.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Comment: You're _assuming_ that time zone is important to OP, and that they're not just after "24 hours ago" for the previous day.  Until they answer Basil's question, we can't know for sure.  It may be that a simpler answer, just using `Instant`, is sufficient for their purposes.

Comment: Thanks Ole! Yes would also like to consider other time anormalies too, that is a good catch. Is there a way to know the user's system time zone, as the user might be from different timezone? Is it TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault(); 
Also curious about using  the Instant, would you please update the answer for the other option which is considering 24 hours ago. Thanks much.

Comment: Yes, @user7046311, `ZoneId.systemDefault()` gives you the default time zone as a `ZoneId`. Please see my edit to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can proceed as follow:

```
// remove the 60 seconds time 60 minutes * 1000 (for millisecond)
long previousHourEpoch = epoch - (60*60*1000);

// remove the 24 hours * 60 seconds time 60 minutes * 1000 (for millisecond)
long previousDayEpoch = epoch - (24*60*60*1000);
```

Comment: We have the *java.time* classes for this. No need to do the math.